# Words are cut in first line of ion-item in ion-list

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Io ionic 3, I am using an ion-list, inside it I have an ion-item, but first line inside each ion-item is cut. As you can see, the capital 'A' letter is not entirely visibile.
Can you help me? Thanks

This is my code and my screenshot

```
<ion-list>
 <li *ngFor="let risultato of risultatiFiltered">
  <ion-item text-wrap>
   <h3> Activity: {{risultato.activity}} </h3>          
   <h3> Time: {{risultato.time}} </h3>
   <h3> Score: {{risultato.score}} </h3>
  </ion-item>
 </li>
</ion-list>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am not familiar with `ionic` but it could be your `line-height` in your `css` that is too small. Try setting it higher than your textsize.

Comment: just give it a margin or padding top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears to affect all of the `<ion-item />` elements and not just the first (and / or last) one(s), I would start by trying to change the `font-size` or `overflow` of the `<ion-item />` tag.

For example, you could use the `overflow-y` property to remove the top / bottom *"cropping"* (sorry, I have no better word to describe it):

```
ion-item {
  overflow-y: visible
}
```

You could also try to make the `font-size` smaller, for example, if your current `font-size` is `16px`, you could try to set it to:

```
ion-item {
  font-size: 14px
}
```

Although you should tweak it to see what works best.

**UPDATE:** are you using `box-sizing`? Because if you aren't you should check the padding as it might be affect the `<ion-item />` element's size, causing it to hide it's overflow.

If that's the case then removing it using:

```
ion-item {
  overflow-y: visible
}
```

Should work. You could also remove the overflow in it's entirety using:

```
ion-item {
  overflow: visible
}
```

Good luck.